# No data entry into firebase database on page redirection

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The above code redirects me to the required page, but doesn't enter data into the database.

If I remove `window.location.href` command, the data is successfully entered in the database.

I want to do both the task together. What is the way out?

```js
var firebasep = firebase.database().ref();
var cool = firebasep.child(i.value).set(j.value);
console.log(cool);
firebasep.set(newData, function(error) {
  alert("New");
  window.location.href="Votingpage.html";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use promises as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#receive_a_promise) to figure out when it's safe to redirect the user to Votingpage.html

```
firebasep.set(newData).then(function(data){
  alert("New");
  window.location.href="Votingpage.html";
}).catch(function(error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Awesome glad it worked! Can you pick this as the best answer?

Answer (score 0):

It redirects you to the required page but doesn’t enter data into the database because the query failed but you mistakenly put your redirection code inside of the error callback, fix you code up like this to make it clearer to see what's happening

```
firebase.set(newData)
  .then((data) => {
      // redirect here
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     // display error here
  });
```